# couldn't parse date : nxlog

Tags: linux, logging, parsing

While debugging my log parsing in *Nxlog*, i got the below error

2019-03-31 01:57:31 DEBUG couldn't parse date: Mar 30, 2019 4:53:56 AM

---

I have used the below command to parse date :

Exec $time = strftime(parsedate($EventTime),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');

Find the EventTime parsed from log successfully.

EventTime =  Mar 30, 2019 4:53:56 AM

---

My Event log is here:

Mar 30, 2019 5:23:56 AM AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run

Please help...!

Answer (score -1):

It's resolved by applying the below line in the nxlog Config File  :

Exec $time = strptime($1,'%b%t%d,%n%EY%t%r');

Have a great time ahead...!